# Can I use the verb 'to do' to emphasize the verb 'can'?

Tags: semantics, emphasis, do, can-could

The verb 'to do' can be used to emphasize things, e.g.: *I do understand it*.

Can it be used to emphasize a sentence that uses the verb 'can'? E.g.: *I do can play football*.

**If not, how could I achieve the above?**

Comment: short answer:  no, you can't.

Comment: "I really can play football", or, more formally "I can indeed...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matter is one of grammar.  In the context you are talking about, *do* is acting as an auxiliary in the *have* does.  The problem is the use of a double auxiliary.  This can happen with the tense and voice auxiliaries, *have* and *be*, but not with ‘do’.

Even here there is an exception.  Somerset dialect, now sadly moribund, permits

> “I do go to the gym every Tuesday” or even
>
> He do be looking for the way to the chemist.

But this is seldom heard today.  It was educated out of children by the school system years ago.

So instead of *I do can*, you can can say I *really can*

Answer (score 0):

No, it depends on your intent.
You could say “I can do football”, with a literal meaning being that you are capable of football and an implied, more colloquial meaning that you are capable of (joining) football. 
I don’t know if there is a deeper, more exact rule, but as a native English speaker that’s how you’d sentences akin to this one.